Optional filter on query with sqlc w/ Postgres in Golang
I'm writing a query where I want to fetch some asset transactions from my database, I'm using sqlc to generate queries for me, but I cannot figure out how to do this properly.
I want to give an optional asset ID (UUID). If the asset ID given is null (represented by a pgtype.UUID{Valid: false}) then I want to fetch all asset transactions irrespective of the asset, but when I provide a non-null value, I want asset transactions only for that asset ID.
This is my query at the moment:
SELECT * FROM asset_txn WHERE asset_id = $1;

ChatGPT suggested some things like:
SELECT * FROM asset_txn WHERE asset_id = COALESCE($1, asset_id)

The problem is that when sqlc generates the code for the query, the asset ID comes as a uuid.UUID, not a pgtype.UUID, meaning that I cannot give a null value. This is expected behaviour though, because my asset_id is a required field. Need help figuring out how to check if the asset_id is null and then proceed.

Based on the snippets provided, what you're basically saying is that you only want to have a WHERE clause if you have an asset id to filter the results by. Cool, so check for the asset ID, and add the where clause to your query when needed. No SQL trickery needed, really. KISS

Do you have an example you could show me with sqlc? I want to avoid writing direct queries in my code and unstructuring it myself.

I would simply write 2 queries and call them GetAllAssets and GetAssetByID.

Got an answer from this comment:
Just modified my query like the following:
SELECT * FROM asset_txn 
WHERE (asset_id = $1 
    OR NOT @filter_by_asset_id::bool);

This allowed me to add an asset_id if I wanted to filter by one, otherwise it selects all asset transactions.
Another option is from here:
SELECT * FROM asset_txn 
WHERE asset_id = COALESCE(sqlc.narg('asset_id'), asset_id);

